# Why the code in my app.xaml.cs is not executed? I am trying to configure dependency injection

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection

I am trying to configure dependency injection in my WPF application, but the code in the app.xaml.cs is not run.

This is the code in my app.xaml.cs file:

```
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;


namespace GTS.CMMS.Client
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            AppHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    string dummy = "Dummy";
                    dummy = dummy + " ";
                })
                .Build();
        }


        public static IHost? AppHost { get; private set; }


        protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            string dummy = "asd";
            dummy = dummy + " ";
        }

        protected override async void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            string dummy = "assada";
            dummy = dummy + " ";
        }
    }
}
```

To simplify, I just put a string that I modify, to set some breakpoints, but the code doesn't is not executed.

I remove from the file app.xaml the StartUpUri configuration, because it has to be set in the OnStartUp() method of the app.xaml.cs.

But I don't understand why the code is not executed.

Thanks.

Comment: Any chance there is more involved with the startup? If I just replicate your override (even if I mark them async like you do) it just works for me.

Comment: I created a new empty project, I copy all from the first one to the second and it works. So it seems that there is something about configuration in the project that gives problems, because when I copy all from this to the new one, all the classes and code, references.... work.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía: How do you start debugging the application? Have you set this as the startup project and run?

Comment: @CharithJ Yes, I have set it as startup project, and I click the debug botton. If i set breakpoints in another parts of code, another classes, it stop in the breakpoint, but it seems that the code in app.xaml.cs is not executed for some reason. I have realized too that when I debug this project, loading symbols take a lot of time. In the new project it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove async from both OnStartup and OnExit override methods.

Reason: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.